# Error de instalación de SASS

Tags: css3, web, sass, preprocesador

Buenas tardes y buen comienzo de años para todo. Quiero consultarles sobre un problema que tengo al querer instalar SASS a mi equipo (Mismo error en una laptop y una PC de escritorio). Realice la instalación como decía la pagina oficial. Instalar ruby y a través del CMD del mismo instalar SASS, pero me salta el siguiente error, en ambas computadoras tengo Windows 10 pro x64, e instale el que corresponde a la versión de x64

```
ERROR:  Error installing sass:
    The last version of ffi (< 2, >= 0.5.0) to support your Ruby & RubyGems was 1.9.18. Try installing it with `gem install ffi -v 1.9.18` and then running the current command again
    ffi requires Ruby version < 2.5, >= 2.0. The current ruby version is 2.5.0.
```

por lo que puedo observar, tiene que ver con las versiones. espero que me puedan ayudar, así arranco el año con todo. Saludos.

Comment: ¿Has probado a actualizar la versión con el comando que pone en el mensaje de error? ¿Recibes algún otro mensaje de error al hacerlo?

Comment: Si intente actualizar lo que me pide pero, sigue saliendo un error.

Comment: Me sale el siguente error, creo que no estoy entendiendo bien que me pide ERROR:  Error installing sass:
        The last version of ffi (< 2, >= 0.5.0) to support your Ruby & RubyGems was 1.9.18. Try installing it with `gem install ffi -v 1.9.18` and then running the current command again
        ffi requires Ruby version < 2.5, >= 2.0. The current ruby version is 2.5.0.

Comment: ¿Ese es el error que te sale al hacer `gem install ffi -v 1.9.18`?

Comment: Si ese es el error que sale cuando intento actualizar ffi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hoy me encontré con este mismo problema y descubrí que desinstalando Ruby 2.5 y luego la reinstalando Ruby 2.4.3 resolvió el problema. Parece que `ffi` no era compatible con Ruby 2.5, y creo que es necesario para instalar sass. Encontré Ruby 2.4.3 aquí: https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/